# How to call another view models constructor in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I've got a method that authenticates a users login.  If the user correctly logs in I'd like to call two view models contructors just in case the user has logged in.  Below is my sample code.  What is the best way to acheive this?

Sending view model:

```
        if (UserName == userName && Password == password)
        {
            ProjectManager.Instance.IsAdmin = true;
            isLoggedIn = true;
            IsLoggedIn = true;
            ValidLoginImage();
            LoginStatus = "Admin Logged In";
            MessengerInstance.Send(true);

        }
```

Receiving View Model:

```
    private void RegisterForMessages()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Register<bool>(this, UpdateEnabled);
    }

    private void UpdateEnabled(bool b)
    {
        IsLoggedIn = b;
    }
```

The registerformessage method never gets called.

Comment: so why can't you just do ViewModel vm=new ViewModel()?

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen  I tried that and it seems that the IsLoggedIn Property changed on the view model I'm calling which is a IsEnabled for UI Controls for that new view model do get set to the right state which is true but the UI items aren't enabled.

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is clicking on a view then going back to another view then logging in do I need to call the view to refresh as well?

Comment: while i'm not sure what you're doing, you could possibly make your view model a static instance.  or use MvvmLight Messenger to send a message to the other viewmodel that updates it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx

Comment: not sure why you are trying to call a constructor when the view model already exists...

Comment: Ok so basically I have a log in screen on one view.  On another view there is a boolean for the IsEnabled that is set based on whether a user is logged in.  I'm looking for the easiest way to refresh a view based on whether someone is logged in or not regardless of what view the user uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using MvvmLight, I'd just send a message containing a boolean that calls a method in the view model to update it.  Register for the messages in the view model that needs updating.  Then it will wait for the "ok i'm logged in" boolean, then run some method that updates your IsEnabled property.  Put this in the view model that needs to be updated:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Listen for messages from other ViewModels
        /// </summary>
        private void RegisterForMessages()
        {
            MessengerInstance.Register<bool>(this, UpdateMyStuff);
        }

private void UpdateMyStuff(bool b)
        {
            IsEnabled=b;
        }
```

Then send the message when the user logs in this with this:

//logged in successfully code here...

```
MessengerInstance.Send(true);  //or your IsLoggedIn property
```

you can send false if this view has logout or whatever.

This will let your view model know the status of whether the user is logged in, and allow you to update accordingly.  obviously, you need to make sure you implement INotifyPropertyChanged etc.  This is all part of MVVMLight already.  If your viewmodel implements MvvmLight's ViewModelBase, it will already be ready for you.

Comment: Awesome.  This is what I was looking for.  Thank you very much for your patience I really appreciate it.

Comment: Gimme a sec to implement then I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Ok I implemented but the Register for Messages never received a message.

Comment: put the register in your constructor, so when its created, it registers to receive the message.  in other words, the RegisterForMessages must be called explicitly by you.  do this when the viewmodel is created (in the constructor)